# Sending HTTPS POST request with ABAP

Tags: https, abap

I'm trying to send https post request using either FM HTTP_POST or class CL_HTTP_CLIENT but I wasn't successful yet.

To test my code I'm using https://ptsv2.com.

When posting to HTTP everything works fine but when I send a request to HTTPS I'm getting:

- "OpenSSL not available" for rfc destination SAPHTTP.
- "SapSSL error: SSSLERR_SSL_CONNECT" for default rfc destination -
  SAPHTTPA

I think the problem might be from the BASIS site, I've already tried doing some magic with SM59/STRUST but those changed nothing so I was probably just messing around.

If anyone has any tips or sample codes(preferably with adresses to test) I'd be happy to try it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the server SSL certificate root CA with t-code `STRUST` into the PSE `SSL Client (Anonymous)`. Also you need to know the exact handshake configuration with your server. If your server only supports `TLS 1.2`, your SAP system must have `commoncryptolib` (sapcryptolib) at least 8.431 and the profile parameter `ssl/client_ciphersuites` must be configured. You can check the commoncryptolib version with the program `SSF02`.

If you need to investigate in details, you can go to t-code `SMICM`. Configure the trace level as 2 (Goto -> Trace Level -> Set). Reset trace file (Goto -> Trace File -> Reset) for removing old logs. Run your program again and check trace file (Goto -> Trace File -> Display All).

Comment: Is this the thing I as a programmer should do? Sounds like basis stuff and I should try to let them do this instead...

I guess I'll mark this as a correct answer (at least for now) :)
Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Seems like configuration is done (not sure if correct tho), crytpolib version is higher.
I'll mess around with certificates in STRUST.

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

STRUST won't help, if you try to connect from the SAP GUI. This is where destination SAPHTTP goes to. In this case SAP note 2979489 might help.